# What happened to the star ratings in the Music app in iOS 9.3?

Tags: ios, itunes, music

So I just updated to iOS 9.3 and everything seems fine overall. But when I launch the Music app, I used to be able tap on the name of a track while it was playing to view/edit the star rating. But now if I do that it just oddly brings me to the same track again… And again… And again…

Is this a “feature” or something? The UX on this seems weird. Is Apple ditching star rating for the hearts/love thing? What’s the deal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I accidentally figured this issue out. Where before you could click on  the name of a track to view/edit the star rating, now the UX for that is to click on the album artwork. The artwork blurs and the star ratings show up dead center in that area; see picture below.

Still doesn’t explain the weird UX of tapping the current track name bringing you to the same current track name again and again. But at least star ratings are still a part of the Music app in iOS 9.3!

[image: Screenshot of the star ratings that now appear in the cover area in the iOS 9.3 Music app.]

Comment: Clicking on the track name in 9.3 will bring you to the album of said track. Something a lot of people were clamoring for.

Comment: It's true—clicking on the album artwork now reveals the star ratings. The UX change is definitely an upgrade (although confusing at first)—if you search for a "song" (instead of an album) and want to view the entire album, clicking the title is much faster than clicking the **...** (three dots, bottom-right) and finding the album that way. Hope that better explains the reasoning behind their decision to move the star ratings!

Comment: Thank you for posting a solution. I was about to go postal!